# The date 2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z gives me previous month (March, not April)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

So, I have the 1st day of month as `2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z`

When I use `moment(date).month()`, it returns me 2, not 3. 
So, I receive March, not April.

What is the problem with it, and why I receive the previous month from the date? Maybe the problem in the TimeZone? Because my TimeZone is `GMT-4`, so, maybe this is problem?

Should I use `UTC` or `ISO` string instead to work with the date?

Comment: What is the day and hour you're getting back? I think momentjs will convert it to your local time. Because the date that you use is in UTC. You can tell by the 'Z' at the end (Zulu time)

Comment: How can I play around to get the month? I found getUTCMonth, right now it works well.

Comment: `Because my TimeZone is GMT-4, so, maybe this is problem? ` yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, your timezone is `GMT-4`. The date that you are providing is in UTC. The 'Z' at the end stands for Zulu time, which is the same as UTC.
`momentjs` will convert this to local time.

How to handle this all depends on what you need the date for.
If this is a date that you saved somewhere before on a server, it might be important to add the correct timezone to it when you are saving it.
Be careful if you let a server create these dates, because the server might be running in a different timezone than your client. 
If you create a `new Date()` in JS it will return a date object with the current time of your local time. If this happens on a server that's running in a different timezone, or in UTC (for example Docker containers), it will create a date in that timezone.

The best way to solve this is to **think about your exact use case**.
There are tons of articles written about handling dates and it's not easy.
If you have some time, this podcast helps to explain how dates work and will help you to get a better understanding of dates in general:
[Coding Blocks - Why Date-ing Is Hard](https://www.codingblocks.net/podcast/why-date-ing-is-hard/)